# Table remove with non-integer keys

Tags: lua

I wanted to make my `removeIf(aTable, unaryPredicate)` function that removes elements that satisfy the predicate.

I've written the following code on a hunch, and surprisingly for me it works:

```
for k, v in pairs(aTable) do
    if unaryPredicate(v) then
        atable[k] = nil
    end
end
```

What is the magic behind `next` or `pairs` that allows this code to work. As far as I see it iterates exactly sizeof(aTable) times.

Comment: There is no `next` in the code. And `counter` plays no visible role.

Comment: Counter is there by mistake. next is returned by pairs?

Comment: My guess is that pairs makes a deep copy of the table, so next knows how to iterate over the table despite elements being removed during iteration.

Comment: `pairs` does not copy anything.

Comment: Well, I don't know how it should work with only a reference being kept. But, as i said it's only a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua tables are implemented essentially as hashtables. The hashtable stores an array of `(key, value)` pairs.

**[next](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/ltable.c.html#luaH_next)** uses a hash to quickly skip to where they key should be in the table.

However, notice that there is a `nil` check in the implementation of `next`:

```
if (!ttisnil(&t->array[i])) {  /* a non-nil value? */
```

This is because when `nil` is assigned to a key of a table, it updates the (key, value) pair inside the hashtable, but does not actually *delete* that entry. Thus you're left with a (key, `nil`) entry in the hashtable. This design allows iteration via `next` to continue unaffected when *existing* keys are assigned values, *including* when assigning to `nil`.

However, this is an *implementation detail*. Whether or not there is a `nil` entry in the hashtable is entirely invisible in the API exposed by the table implementation. Every function externally treats these `nil` keys in exactly the same way as absence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! that clarifies a lot. Would u say leveraging this implementation to create removeIf is  bad practice?

Comment: Lua explicitly guarantees that modifying existing keys will not affect iteration order: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-next

Answer (score 1):

`next` depends only on the keys in the table. The loop removes values but not keys (in the current implementation of Lua). The documentation explicitly says that you may remove values from tables in a loop like yours. It also says that you cannot add new entries with new keys, exactly because this would confuse `next`.

Comment: I log the table after setting the value to nil. No key belonging to that value exits at that moment. This would seem to agree with [storing nils in tables](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StoringNilsInTables)  post on lua users wiki that says: " Lua tables make no distinction between a table value being nil and the corresponding key not existing in the table."